# How do I target a previous Element child by <tag> that is further back than just the previous element?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom, button, copy

The problem I am having is targeting the text in the input tag in the HTML below with Button that is Copying that text (words). What do i need to change to the JS to get it to target that Input value?

I want to do this without using ID - as I plan on replicating this many many times and don't want to set up individual Id's for the Input tags.

If there is a way to refer to the Class - 'columns-small-8' - child element, then maybe that would work?

Thanks in advance

JS

```
<script> 

window.onload=function(){
let btns = document.getElementsByTagName("button")
Array.from(btns).forEach(ele => {
  ele.addEventListener("click", function() {
   jimsFunction(this)
  });
})  
function jimsFunction(input) {
  let x = input.previousElementSibling
  let ele = x.previousElementSibling
  ele.select()
  ele.setSelectionRange(0, 99999)
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(ele.value)
  alert("Copied: " + ele.value)
}}

</script>
```

HTML

```
       <div>
          <div class="row collapse">
            <div class="columns small-8">
              <input type="text" value="words" readonly>
            </div>
            <div class="columns small-2">
              <a class="button full-width secondary" href="www.google.com" 
              target="_blank">View</a>                                
            </div>
            <div class="columns small-2">
              <button type="button" class="button full-width secondary">Copy URL</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your html structure, you can call to parent of it same as :

```js
window.onload=function(){
let btns = document.getElementsByTagName("button")
Array.from(btns).forEach(ele => {
  ele.addEventListener("click", function() {
   jimsFunction(this)
  });
})  
function jimsFunction(input) {
  let x = input.parentElement.parentElement
  let ele = x.firstElementChild.firstElementChild
  ele.select()
  ele.setSelectionRange(0, 99999)
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(ele.value)
  alert("Copied: " + ele.value)
}}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="row collapse">
    <div class="columns small-8">
      <input type="text" value="words" readonly>
    </div>
    <div class="columns small-2">
      <a class="button full-width secondary" href="www.google.com" 
      target="_blank">View</a>                                
    </div>
    <div class="columns small-2">
      <button type="button" class="button full-width secondary">Copy URL</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Xupitan appreciate your response. I got this error in console: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'select') - this referring to ele.select()

Comment: I figured out what the problem was. I had an additional Element in my HTML that was interferring! Thanks :) !